# SSIS - The table cannot be created Microsoft jet database engine could not find object

Tags: ssis, export-to-excel

I am trying to load a sql table into an excel file using SSIS package.
But while I add Excel connection manager to my Excel destination , adding the name of the excel sheet using the New button throws the following error.

The table cannot be created
***Additional information***
The Microsoft Jet database engine could not find the object 'Address'. Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly(Microsoft Jet Database Engine)

Please  help me in this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, and it was caused by the list of the fields, not because of the Excel version.

My list of fields had a "LongBinary" field.

[image]

When I removed it, the creation of the Connection worked.

So, check if you have any fields with this type, and remove them.

Hope it works (it worked for me, at least)

Answer (score 1):

Check the version of excel sheet. It will works only for 97-2003 version.

Please save with that version and then you can able to select the sheet name as table in excel destination.

[image]

then map your columns and run the package....

---