# SSIS SQL Server to Excel

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis

I am trying to use SSIS to export a `BigInt` data type from SQL Server 2016 to Excel 2016 (`.xlsx`).

I'm having trouble with mapping the `BigInt` column to Excel. What is the data type to use for Excel?

Thanks

Comment: What's specifically is the "trouble" you are having?

Comment: I create my data flow task, and have ole db as my data source, this is connecting to sql server 2016. I create an Excel connection, excel 2016. I point to a new file. When I map my data source to my Excel Destination I need to make a new table, when I do that it says the table cannot be created. The BIGINT data type in the Excel table is the problem field. If I remove the big int column from my data source it works fine

Comment: Can you find the table creation script as per here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28743291/ssis-the-table-cannot-be-created-microsoft-jet-database-engine-could-not-find and change the data type fron BIGINT to DECIMAL or something like that. OR simply export to a csv file, not XLSX (although I realise you may have some requirement to load into excel)

Comment: Choosing data type DECIMAL worked. Thanks.

Comment: It would be awsome if you could write up the solution in detail so anyone else with the problem can find it. Then you can accept your own answer.

Comment: Sure, will provide detail